# Postfix, multi domains and multi certs on one IP

Tags: ssl, postfix, ssl-certificate

I've a postfix server which has multi domains and I want to have a specific cert per each. My server has only one IP.

I've found a solution with multi IP, but without I don't know how to do this.

- Server : Debian 9
- Postfix : 3.1.8

Comment: My server is hosting multi domains and I manage every DNS zone. Each domain has a DNS record which is pointing on the same server. Then, I want to configure Postfix and dovecot to use one certificate per domain. Hope it's clear your mind

Comment: First, I prefer to have one certificate per domain to keep separation between each domains. Second, if you add your mail on Gmail, if you serve a generic certificate for each mail with a different domain, it will be refused because of mismatching CN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far i know there is no working SNI in postfix . Yet. Docs ( http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html ) say that "There are no plans to implement SNI in the Postfix SMTP server.", though Victor mentioned in January that he wants to add SNI support to postfix 3.4 .
Alternatives :

- multiple ip
- certificate containing all domain names.

Also there is nothing wrong with having the same MX for all domains. MX hostname being your service domain or something. Also helo/ehlo name configured to the same/similar hostname . If its good for GoogleApps and other major email providers, then its good for us too.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. See below and see Postfix documentation: https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#tls_server_sni_maps

Answer (score 29):

If you are on Postfix >=3.4, consider the following steps below as adapted [from this link](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/How-to-use-the-new-server-TLS-SNI-feature-3-4-x-td100786.html#a101029):

**Step 1**: Comment out the top two lines and add the follow lines to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
    # smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
    # smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
    
    # provide the primary certificate for the server, to be used for outgoing connections (note the indentation)
    smtpd_tls_chain_files =
        /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/privkey.pem,
        /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/fullchain.pem
    
    # provide the map to be used when SNI support is enabled
    tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
```

**Step 2**: Create the file /etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map with the following:

```
    # Compile with postmap -F hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map when updating
    # One host per line
    mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yourprimarymailserverdomain.com/fullchain.pem
    mail.yoursecondarymailserverdomain.com /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yoursecondarymailserverdomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.yoursecondarymailserverdomain.com/fullchain.pem
    # add more domains with keys and certs as needed
```

**Step 3**: Run `postmap -F hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map`.

**Step 4**: Run `systemctl restart postfix`.

**Step 5**: Now test your domains' SSLs! For each of your domains, run the following command: `openssl s_client -connect localhost:25 -servername mail.mydomainname.com -starttls smtp`

Answer (score 8):

For those who doesn't know, the SNI table needs to be rebuilt each time a certificate changes as the underlying table is generated with `postmap -F` which imports the file *content* (it does not just store references to the file names).

`postmap -F hash:/etc/postfix/tls_server_sni_maps.map`

Answer (score 2):

Postfix version 3.4 now supports SNI and it's therefore available in Ubuntu 19.10, for example.

Also, there IS a good reason for wanting this - clients such as Outlook attempt autoconfiguration using a servername that matches the email domain name. If your mail account is at Gmail or another shared domain this is not a problem, but a personal domain hosted on a server (even a VPS) with multiple domains needs a solution like this